php check audio file is corrupted or not
I have written below condition to check whether file is corrupted or not. Even if file is corrupted it is showing not corrupted
function checkAudio($filename) {
    
    // Open the file and read the first few bytes (usually enough to determine file type)
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($filename, false, null, 0, 100); // Read first 100 bytes
    
    // Analyze file content (adjust the checks based on the format)
    // For example, check for ID3 tag presence in MP3 files
    
    if (strpos($fileContents, 'ID3') === 0) {
        // If the file starts with ID3 tag, but is shorter than expected for a valid ID3 tag, consider it corrupted
       
        if (strlen($fileContents) < 10) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check if the ID3 version is supported (adjust as needed)
        $version = ord($fileContents[3]);
        
        if ($version < 2 || $version > 4) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check if the size field of the ID3 tag header is valid
        $tagSize = (ord($fileContents[6]) & 0x7F) << 21 |
                   (ord($fileContents[7]) & 0x7F) << 14 |
                   (ord($fileContents[8]) & 0x7F) << 7 |
                   (ord($fileContents[9]) & 0x7F);

        if ($tagSize < 10) { // Minimum ID3 tag size is 10 bytes
            return false;
        }

    }

    // Add more checks for other audio formats as needed

    
    return true;
}

Audio file output : corrupted or not

At a first glance: you wrote if (strpos($fileContents, 'ID3') === 0) { ... } if the file does not start with ID3 you return true => not corrupted?.

@Eineki, if file doesnot starts with ID3 , return corrupted. but in my case. corrupted files which i have starts with ID3 only

corrupted is true? It seems to be false (in the if branch) but it is not clear. Can you add a sample of two of the $filecontents values?

yes. for corrupted true

Your definition of "(not) corrupted" seems pretty narrow in scope. Even if you find a perfectly valid ID3 tag - the rest of the file content could still be gibberish, instead of actual valid mp3 audio data.

I found something to fix. The code was a bit obscure for me and in some tests you do the opposite of what is written in the comments. It is a common behaviour, expecially for beginners and you have not to worry about that, just code with a bit more care than usual.
The first thing I did is remove some complexity in your function and do a bit of renaming to let the things clearer.
Your function was called checkAudio and this led to confusion. At least for me. If the function returns true, it means the file is corrupted or not?
To clarify the thing I renamed your funtion in isMp3Corrupted, a couple more chars to type but less code to read to understand what happens inside.
In the chat you stated that corrupted is true but in the code you wrote I read
    // If the file starts with ID3 tag, but is shorter than 
    // expected for a valid ID3 tag, consider it corrupted
    if (strlen($fileContents) < 10) {
            return false;
    }

In the comment just before the if you wrote if the tag is shorter the
file is corrupted but then you return false. => it seems that false is corrupted
The body of your function is wrapped in a single if test:
    $fileContents = file_get_contents($filen ... );
    if (strpos($fileContents, 'ID3') === 0) {
       ... 
       // all your computation
       ...
    }

    // Add more checks for other audio formats as needed
    
    return true;

if the file does not start with ID3 return true => it seems that true is corrupted
To get rid of this contradiction AND make it stand out when it happens, I changed the name of the function and rewrote the whole thing in a more streamlined way.
The complicate parts,  I did not ever bother to check, were factored away from the function body in order to further simplify the code and rearranged the test for an early exit as soon one of them fails.
    /**
     * returns the header (first 100 bytes) of a file or false
     * @returns bool | string
     **/

    function mp3Header($filename) {
        // Open the file and read the first 100 bytes 
        // (usually enough to determine file type)
        $header = file_get_contents($filename, false, null, 0, 100);
        return $header;
    }

    /**
     * This function compute the mp3 tag size
     * I DID NOT TESTED IT -(E)-
     * @return int
     */
    function computeTagSize($bytes) {
        $tagSize = (ord($bytes[0]) & 0x7F) << 21 |
                   (ord($bytes[1]) & 0x7F) << 14 |
                   (ord($bytes[2]) & 0x7F) << 7 |
                   (ord($bytes[3]) & 0x7F);
        return $tagSize;
    }

    /**
     * Check if an mp3 file is corrupted
     * The test is quite simple:
     * - file have to start with ID3 string
     * - version have to be 3
     * - header length have to be greater than 10
     *
     * @return boolean
     **/
    function isMp3Corrupted($filename) {
        $header= mp3Header($filename);
        // can't read or open the file => corrupted
        if ($header=== false) return true;

        // if the file do not start with ID3 it is corrupted
        if (substr($header, 0, 3) !== 'ID3') return true;

        // If the file starts with ID3 tag, but is shorter 
        // than expected for a valid ID3 tag, consider it corrupted
        if (strlen($header) < 10) return true;
        
        // Check if the ID3 version is supported 
        // the version is contained into the fourth byte
        $version = ord($header[3]); // we need the numerical value
        $supportedVersions = [2, 3, 4];
        if (!in_array($version, $supportedVersions)) return true;

        /* TODO: I would double check this, is so similar
         *       to the header lenght test a few lines above
         *       (and then remove this comment -(E 2024-04-12)-
         */
        $tagSize = computeTagSize(substr($header, 6, 4));
        // a tag size should not be less than 10
        if ($tagSize < 10) return true;

        // Passed All tests, the file is good (Not corrupted)
        return false;
    }


now you can write your code in a quite colloquial fashion:
    if (!isMp3Corrupted($mp3filePath)) {
       // do something appropriate
    } else {
       // discard it (maybe?)
    }


thanks for detailed explaination. but file which i have is corrupted but in this function it is showing valid

do you know why it is corrupted?

it is recording url provided by operator .
